# How do I set between two TimeValue

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm having trouble setting the `TimeValue` between 07:00AM to 04:00PM to run a procedure or else run different procedure outside that time.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim FromStart As Date
    Dim ToEnd As Date

    FromStart = TimeValue("07:00:00 AM")
    ToEnd = TimeValue("04:00:00 PM")

    If Weekday(Now()) = vbMonday Or Weekday(Now()) = vbTuesday Or _
       Weekday(Now()) = vbWednesday Or Weekday(Now()) = vbThursday Or _
       Weekday(Now()) = vbFriday And _
       TimeValue(Now()) >= FromStart And TimeValue(Now()) <= ToEnd Then

       ' Do something
       Debug.Print Now
    Else
        ' Do something else
        Debug.Print "bla bla !!!"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This code could be greatly simplified. `DayNow = Weekday(Now())` removes all of those redundant function calls, and then you can use `If (DayNow >= vbMonday And DayNow <= vbFriday)` to simplify your test. Same applies to the `TimeValue` code, which you just And in as well.

Comment: @KenWhite Appreciate it I'll try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code does not work is that there is a problem with boolean order precedence. Since "And" operations precede "Or" operations you get what you did not expect.

If you want your code to work as is, you should add parenthesis around the ORed expression. Of course the code should also be simplified as Ken commented.

```
Public Sub Example()
    Dim FromStart As Date
    Dim ToEnd As Date
    Dim DayNow As Date

    FromStart = TimeValue("07:00:00 AM")
    ToEnd = TimeValue("04:00:00 PM")
    DayNow = Weekday(Now())


    If (DayNow >= vbMonday And DayNow <= vbFriday) And _
        (TimeValue(Now()) >= FromStart And TimeValue(Now()) <= ToEnd) Then
        ' Do something 
        Debug.Print Now
    Else
        ' Do something else
        Debug.Print "bla bla !!!"
    End If
End Sub
```